# Reload template after AJAX POST request in Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, python-2.7

I'm using HTML5 geolocation to get a user's location, then sending the lat/long to my django app to find the three nearest schools. I'm able to post the lat/long, run it through a function to get the closest schools, and print out the dict object in terminal, but the template never reloads with the new context_dict data.

HTML

```
{% csrf_token %}
<input id = 'button' type="submit" value="Use current location" onclick = 'find_school()' class="btn btn-default">
```

JS

```
function find_school(){

function send_off(lat, long){
    var locale = [lat, long];
    console.log(lat, long);
    return locale
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/schools/search/",
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
            lat_pos: position.coords.latitude,
            long_pos: position.coords.longitude
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});
```

}

views.py

```
def find_school(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    search_school_list = search_school_bar()
    if request.GET:
        address = request.GET['q_word']
        close_schools = geolocate(address)
        context_dict = {'close_schools': close_schools, 'search_schools':json.dumps(search_school_list)}
    elif request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        position = request.POST

        #the geo_search view takes the lat and long
        return geo_search(request, position['lat_pos'],position['long_pos'] )
    else:
        context_dict = {'search_schools':json.dumps(search_school_list)}

    return render_to_response('school_data/search.html', context_dict, context)

def geo_search(request, lat, long):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    search_school_list = search_school_bar()

    close_schools = geolocate_gps(lat, long)

    context_dict = {'close_schools': close_schools, 'search_schools':json.dumps(search_school_list)}
    #This print statement returns in my terminal the results, and they are correct. I just need to reload the template to display the results.
    print context_dict
    #This isn't re-rendering the page with the correct context_dict. It is doing nothing.
    return render_to_response('school_data/search.html', context_dict, context)
```

Comment: You can't reload the template unless you reload the whole page which would defeat the purpose of AJAX. You need to return data from your AJAX call and place it into your page dynamically (inside your `success` method)

Comment: I don't mind reloading the whole page, in fact that's what I want to do - and when the page reloads I want the results (the contents of the context_dict in the geo_search view) to feed my template. I'm not sure how else to send geolocation information to one of my views to process it without ajax.

Comment: save the geolocation data to a hidden input and submit the form

Comment: I tried sending users to a new template in my geo_search view: return render_to_response('school_data/geo_search.html', context_dict, context) but that template doesn't load at all after the user presses the geolocate button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return the output of render_to_response to an ajax call, you are returning the HTML as the "data" element in "success:function(data)" in your javascript call. I don't think you want to be using AJAX if your goal is to reload the page.

You should have something like:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
 var form = $('<form action="/geosearch/" method="POST"></form>');
 var long =$('<input name = "long" type="hidden"></input>');
 var lat =$('<input name = "lat" type="hidden"></input>');
 lat.val(position.coords.latitude);
 long.val(position.coords.latitude);
 form.append(lat, long);
 $('body').append(form);
 form.submit();
}
```

And your view at /geosearch/ should take the post variables, do whatever you want, and then render_to_response.

Comment: While I didn't use this exact method, I did use a variation where I put the form input right on the html page. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Isaac Ray I want the positions (lat,lng) in a Point(x,y) format. And I am having csrf cookie not set Forbidden 403 message when trying to post.